# displaying Java output text in a web browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, fileoutputstream

I have simple code to execute commands from cmd in windows xp
I would like to display output in IE and Chrome browser instead of notepad

Thank you for the tips,

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(
("C:\\Documents and Settings\\jszpakow\\Desktop\\ping.txt"));
```

---

thank you very much for advices. I'm new here so I know in the future I should be more specific. it's nothing wrong with notepad++, or browser as a text viewer (however when I create html text is not raw like in notepad)

My idea was not to open each time CMD and copy ping output to my case notes which is in web browser system (based on Liferay)

My problem is that I need to paste this ping output in my case notes in specific field textarea in the browser tab, but each time url and textarea ID is different.

(source html) textarea id="xx:caseViewForm:caseViewTabView:caseNotesInput"

so maybe I can send output to buffer and paste it using ctrl + v

the other thing when I tried to use xml or docx file as output, it creates them but I can't open it. (I'm receiving message corrupted file)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you dont want to write some sort of web server or web services. If your just double clicking on a file to see its output, rename the output textfile to .html

You can even print out html tags and format the text to make it look nicer.

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter( ("C:\Documents and Settings\jszpakow\Desktop\ping.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you'd like to use a web browser as a text file viewer, they can do that by default. The URL format is `file://$path`, so in this case:

```
file://C:\Documents and Settings\jszpakow\Desktop\ping.txt
```

Renaming the file extension to .html would make your browser the default viewer, but you'll loose formatting on raw text.

However, if you mean you'd like to make the output available to other people on the web, you'd need a publicly-accessible web server to upload to. This means you'd either have to install and configure WAMP on your local machine, or get a web hosting account and FTP the file.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with notepad? You haven't used Notepad++, have you? Use it, it's will be far better than any browser.